# Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am new to vue JS and got stuck in vue class component creation
I am using following setup:

@rails/webpacker: "^5.1.1"
typescript: "^4.0.2"
vue: "^2.6.11"
vue-class-component: "^7.2.5"

Here is my code:

MockChat.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="mock-chat" class="container" v-cloak>
    <div class="row">
      <Chat
        :messages="messages"
        :handleCmdEnter="handleCmdEnter"
        :handleBtnEnter="handleBtnEnter"
      />
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="inputs" class="col-md-12">
          <label for="agent_id">Agent ID</label>
          <input
            placeholder="Agent ID Input"
            v-model="selectedAgentId"
            type="text"
            name="agent_id"
            class="form-control"
            rows="1"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <Sidebar
            :businessUnit="selectedBusinessUnit"
            :businessUnits="businessUnits"
            :graph="selectedGraph"
            :graphs="graphs"
            :selectGraph="selectGraph"
            :state="state"
            :dataTopics="dataTopics"
            :recommendation="recommendation"
            :messages="messages"
            :handleCmdEnter="handleCmdEnter"
            :handleBtnEnter="handleBtnEnter"
            :handleNextIndex="handleNextIndex"
            :sendText="sendText"
            :selectBusinessUnit="selectBusinessUnit"
            :getBusinessUnitData="getBusinessUnitData"
            :backResponse="backResponse"
            :handleTopicSwitch="handleTopicSwitch"
            :topicSwitchEnabled="topicSwitchEnabled"
            :backButtonEnabled="backButtonEnabled"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
// @ts-ignore
import Chat from "./components/mock_chat/Chat.vue";
// @ts-ignore
import Sidebar from "./components/mock_chat/Sidebar.vue";
import $ from "jquery";

@Component({
  components: {
    Chat,
    Sidebar
  }
})
export default class MockChat extends Vue {
  // Props
  @Prop() businessUnit: string;
  @Prop() businessUnits: string[];
  @Prop() topics: string[];
  @Prop() chatUid: number;
  @Prop() topicSwitchEnabled: boolean;
  @Prop() backButtonEnabled: boolean;
  @Prop() graph: string;
  @Prop() graphs: string[];

  // data
  // data: {
  //   messages: any[];
  // };

  messages: any[];
  state: object;
  recommendation: object;
  selectedBusinessUnit: string = this.businessUnit;
  selectedGraph: string = this.graph;
  dataTopics: string[] = this.topics;
  selectedTopic: string;
  selectedAgentId: string = "";
  mockview: boolean = true;

  // lifecycle methods
  created() {
    // this.getBusinessUnitData();
  }

  // methods
  sendMessage(role, message) {
    let apiName = this.businessUnits.find(
      businessUnit => businessUnit[1] === this.selectedBusinessUnit
    )[1];
    let graphUuid = this.selectGraphUuid();
    let selectedAgentId = this.selectedAgentId;
    let params = {
      chat_uid: this.chatUid,
      role: role,
      message: message,
      business_unit: apiName,
      graph: graphUuid,
      agent_id: selectedAgentId
    };
    $.post("/mock_chat/message", params, data => {
      this.recommendation = data;
      this.messages.push({
        role: params.role,
        message: params.message,
        responses: data.responses,
        nodeName: data.node_name
      });
      if (data.state) {
        this.state = data.state.patient_info;
      }
      this.resetAfterMessage();
    });
  }

  resetAfterMessage() {
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      document.getElementById("transcript-row").scrollTop = 100000;
    });
  }

  selectGraphUuid() {
    if (this.graphs.length) {
      return this.graphs.find(graph => graph[1] === this.selectedGraph)[1];
    }
    // If there are no graphs send nothing to the back end, where it can be handled
    return null;
  }

  handleBtnEnter(e) {
    let role = e.target.role.value;
    let message = e.target.message.value;
    this.sendMessage(role, message);
  }

  handleCmdEnter(e) {
    let role = e.target.form.role.value;
    let message = e.target.form.message.value;
    e.target.form.message.value = "";
    this.sendMessage(role, message);
  }

  handleTopicSwitch(apiName) {
    var that = this;
    let graphUuid = this.selectGraphUuid();
    let selectedAgentId = this.selectedAgentId;
    var params = {
      chat_uid: this.chatUid,
      topic: apiName,
      business_unit: this.selectedBusinessUnit,
      graph: graphUuid,
      agent_id: selectedAgentId
    };
    $.post("/mock_chat/topic", params, function(data) {
      that.recommendation = data;
      that.messages.push({
        nodeName: data.node_name,
        role: "system",
        message: "new topic: " + apiName,
        responses: data.responses
      });
      that.resetAfterMessage();
    });
  }

  handleNextIndex(index) {
    let params = {
      chat_uid: this.chatUid,
      index: index,
      role: "next_click",
      business_unit: this.selectedBusinessUnit
    };
    $.post("/mock_chat/next", params, data => {
      this.recommendation = data;
      this.messages.push({
        role: "system",
        message: "next: " + index,
        responses: data.responses,
        nodeName: data.node_name
      });
      this.resetAfterMessage();
    });
  }

  backResponse() {
    $.post(
      "/mock_chat/back",
      {
        chat_uid: this.chatUid
      },
      data => {
        this.recommendation = data;
        this.messages.push({
          role: "system",
          message: "back",
          responses: data.responses,
          nodeName: data.node_name
        });
        this.resetAfterMessage();
      }
    );
  }

  sendText(text) {
    let role = "agent";
    let message = text;
    this.sendMessage(role, message);
  }

  selectBusinessUnit(event) {
    this.selectedBusinessUnit = event.target.value;
    this.getBusinessUnitData();
  }

  getBusinessUnitData() {
    let params = {
      business_unit: this.selectedBusinessUnit
    };
    $.post("/mock_chat/get_business_unit_data", params, data => {
      this.dataTopics = data.topics;
      this.selectedTopic = data.selected_topic;
    });
  }

  selectGraph(event) {
    this.selectedGraph = event.target.value;
  }
}
</script>
```

here the warning:

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "messages" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property`

I am passing `messages` data to Chat component and its not identifying it.

I am getting this error even when i used data: {} option to declare the data properties.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

resolved:
I have initialize the `messages: any[];` with  `messages: any[] = [];`

and it worked out.

data variables should be initialize to some value make to resolve the issue for rest of the declared data variables here

```
  messages: any[] = [];
  state: object = {};
  recommendation: object = {};
  selectedBusinessUnit: string;
  selectedGraph: string;
  dataTopics: string[];
  selectedTopic: string;
  selectedAgentId: string = "";
  mockview: boolean = true;
```